# SSIS Update Oracle DB

Tags: database, oracle, ssis, sql-update, sqlcommand

Hello and thank you in advanced for reading my question.

I am working in SSIS and trying to take a view in Oracle SQL developer and update any matching rows in a table. By searching around I found out that SSIS has some problems with updating Oracle Databases and you can do it via OLE DB Command. SO What I did was added a OLE DB Source to bring in a View I have created in Oracle SQL Developer. This source has the same exact columns as the destination table. I then connected it to OLE DB Command. I selected the appropriate Connection Manager and I had to add the external columns in the Inputs and Outputs tab to match what the destination table has. This lets me select all of the column mappings. However the issues I am having appear to be with the SQLCommand that I have typed up in the custom properties section of the Component Properties Tab. Can someone with experience in this area please help me with getting this set up? Below is my SQLCommand (It currently gives me an error of "ORA-01008: not all variables bound". when I try to execute):

```
UPDATE DB.PERMDB
SET 
DB.PERMDB.NET_TIME = :NET_TIME,
DB.PERMDB.PROC_ZONENAME = :PROC_ZONENAME,
DB.PERMDB.NET_TIME2 = :NET_TIME2,
DB.PERMDB.PROC_ZONENAME = :PROC_ZONENAME2,
DB.PERMDB.LAST_DISCOVERY = :LAST_DISCOVERY1,
DB.PERMDB.PULSEDATE = :PULSEDATE1
WHERE
DB.PERMDB.COMBREL = :COMBREL1
```

Comment: Are things like `NET_TIME` columns in your data flow?

Comment: Yes... its one of the imported columns from my OLE DB Source, should I be including the view name in front of it? Ex. DB.VIEW.NET_TIME?

Comment: Are you getting `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`, or is the error coming from another layer? The statement looks OK (apart from setting `NET_TIME` to itself, which won't error but might not be what you want).

Comment: I am getting that error when I try to exit out of the OLE DB Command advanced editor. The window won't close and it shows that error. As for setting NET-TIME to itself.... I am trying to update the DB.PERMDB column called NET_TIME with the data listed in the column "NET_TIME" from my OLE DB Source

Comment: You'll need to use `?` as the place holders in your query and then in the next tab, map the SSIS column `NET_TIME` into Parameter_0

Comment: I am getting new erros now... just updated my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a script task to run an UPDATE query and it worked like a charm.